# Not square 9-path drawable

Tags: android, drawable, nine-patch

I need to create not square pin for MapView. I need place a picture inside the pin. When I use square pins I just make 9-path drawable in 9-path editor and set region where picture must be placed.

But what must I do to set content region in non square drawable?

http://s7.postimage.org/5hs3h772f/polygon_9path_example.png

Comment: How do you mean non-square? If you open the PNG in an image editor it will still be square, but with transparency pixels around the edges to make the "filled in" part look non-square. You should be able to use it the same in the draw9patch program. Or do you mean that you don't want it to stretch? Can you post an image of what you are trying to do?

Comment: adding snaps of what you trying to achieve will help more to get answer / also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766778/android-alignment-bug-in-making-showing-9patch-image/10040417#10040417) bw

Comment: I need to place photo in this pin: http://s7.postimage.org/5hs3h772f/polygon_9path_example.png